# unable to save audio recorded in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE3xcajyrAA) tutorial to record and play sounds. but having the problem in saving sound to folder. everything is working fine but when i check the folder where i saved the file then it is empty.

```
String recordPath = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("/").getAbsolutePath();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss", Locale.CANADA);
Date now = new Date();
recordFile = "Recording_"+formatter.format(now)+".3gp";
filenameText.setText("Recording filename : "+recordFile);
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),recordPath+"/"+recordFile,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(recordPath+"/"+recordFile);
```

kindly help me out of it or suggest any other way to record audio files.